# Adding to array siblings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of 10 items:

`| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |`

Each array holds an int of 0.

What I want to do is add a value of 10 to index 4. Then have the 3 outer indexes receive a halved value. Here's a visual example:

`| 0 | 1.25 | 2.5 | 5 | 10 | 5 | 2.5 | 1.25 | 0 |`

So whatever index I chose will receive a value of 10. The first items to the left and right will get that value/2, the further outer ones will receive that value /4, etc.

```
var indexesToCheck = 3; // Will check 3 before and 3 after the selected index
var array = [];
var arrayItems = 10;

for(var i = 0; i < arrayItems.length; i++) {
  array.push(0);
}

function setArrayValue(i, value) {
  array[i] = value;

  // How do I go about checking the next and previous 3 values and setting the halved value?
}

setArrayValue(4, 10);
```

A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What is `arrayItems.length`? I think you just want to put `arrayItems` there

Comment: btw, you have 9 items ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of your example code, it looks like you want to modify the array in place, instead of returning a new one. Below is my implementation:

```js
var indexesToCheck = 3;
var array = new Array(10).fill(0);

function setArrayValue(i, value) {
  array[i] = value;
  for (let j = 1; j <= indexesToCheck; j++) {
    value /= 2;
    array[i - j] = value;
    array[i + j] = value;
  }
}
setArrayValue(4, 10)
console.log(array);
```

Comment: what if I call `setArrayValue(1, 10)`

Comment: Nice catch. Depending on what the goal is, you can break if i-j < 0 or i + j > array.length, or you can only set the value of indices between 0 and array.length.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two pointers, incrementing and decrementing them respectively, until they hit the array boundary.

```js
var indexesToCheck = 3;  //Will check 3 before and 3 after the selected index

//you don't need that variable above

var array = [];
var arrayItems = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayItems; i++) {
  array.push(0);
}

function setArrayValue(i, value) {
  array[i] = value;
  var originalVal = value;

  var pointer1 = i - 1;
  var pointer2 = i + 1;

  while (pointer1 >= 0) {
    array[pointer1] = value / 2;
    value = value / 2;
    pointer1--;
  }

  value = originalVal;

  while (pointer2 < array.length) {
    array[pointer2] = value / 2;
    value = value / 2;
    pointer2++;
  }
}

setArrayValue(4, 10);

console.log(array);
```

Of course, this could be more polished and optimized, but this can get you started as I think this is the easiest and kind of self documented to make it easy to understand the logic, try to think about how you can do that cleanly with just one loop and how you can avoid using that extra variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate and divide the previous number by two every time, then you write to the next index up, and the next index down

```js
var indexesToCheck = 3; // Will check 3 before and 3 after the selected index
var array = [];
var arrayItems = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < arrayItems; i++) {
  array.push(0);
}

function setArrayValue(start, value) {
  array[start] = value;  // set initial
  var prev = value;      // keep previous

  for (var i = 0; i < indexesToCheck; i++) {
    var p = prev / 2;           // divide by two
    if ( (start - i - 1) > -1 )          array[start - i - 1] = p;
    if ( (start + i + 1) < array.length) array[start + i + 1] = p;
    prev = p;
  }
}

setArrayValue(4, 10);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just split your logic into two separate loops.  One will handle halving the values as you go left of the given index, and one will handle it going right.  For example:

```
function initializeArray(array, index, initialValue) {
    array[index] = initialValue;

    var i;

    //Handles logic going left (decreasing indices)
    var currentValue = initialValue;
    for(i = index-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        currentValue /= 2.0;
        array[i] = currentValue;
    }

    //Handles logic going right (increasing indices)
    currentValue = initialValue;
    for(i = index+1; i < array.length; i++) {
        currentValue /= 2.0;
        array[i] = currentValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be

```
var leftIndex = 6; //Index of value
var rightIndex = 6; //Index of value 
var val = 10; //Value at Index 
var arr=[];
arr[leftIndex]=val;
while(leftIndex>0) {
    leftIndex--;
    arr[leftIndex] = arr[leftIndex+1]/2;
}
while(rightIndex<9) {
    rightIndex++;
    arr[rightIndex] = arr[rightIndex-1]/2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the value of the array item.

```js
var length = 9,
    center = 10,
    border = 0,
    array = Array.apply(null, { length: length }).map(function (a, i, aa) {
        return i === 0 || i + 1 === aa.length ?
            border :
            center / (1 << Math.abs(Math.floor(aa.length / 2) - i));
    });

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.  I'm not sure if elements will contain values that you want to preserve or if they should all be overwritten with zeros, for example, but that's an easy change.

```js
var arr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

var changed = doThing(arr, 4, 10, 3); // add 10 to array el 4 and affect elements within 3

function doThing(arr, index, value, spread) {
  return arr.map(function(el, i) {
    var d = Math.abs(index - i);
    if (d <= spread) {
      return value * Math.pow(0.5, d);
    }
    return 0;
  });
}
      
console.log(changed);
```

Comment: it looks like you had a similar idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
// We need to loop over the offset from the original index
for (var offset=1; offset <= indexToCheck; offset++) {
    // We want to handle moving offset to the left
    if(start - offset >= 0){ // Ensure we're still in bounds
        array[start-offset] += value/(2 * offset); // Add value divided by 2 for each offset
    }
    // We want to handle moving offset to the right
    if (start + offset < array.length) { // Ensure we're still in bounds
        array[start+offset] += value/(2 * offset);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = Array(10).fill(0);

const setNum = (pos, num, arr) => { // position, initial number, and array
  const a = arr.slice();
  a[pos] = num;
  for (let i = (pos - 1); i >= 0; i--) { a[i] = a[i+1]/2 }
  for (let i = (pos + 1); i < a.length; i++) { a[i] = a[i-1]/2 }
  return a;
}

console.log(setNum(5, 10, arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic solution to the problem is that:

1. Let *pivot*(in this case pivot = 4) be the index which is assigned *threshold*(in this case threshold=10) value and *indexBoundary*(in this case indexBoundary=3) be the indexes to check.
2. Now *leftStartIndex*=max(0,pivot-indexBoundary) and *rightEndIndex*=min(array.size()-1,pivot+indexBoundary). This will take care of boundary cases as well.
3. Starting from i->pivot-1 to leftStartIndex(including) do array[i] = threshold/2^(pivot-i).
4. Similarly from i->pivot+1 to rightEndIndex(including) do array[i] = threshold/2^(i-pivot).

For your case:

```
pivot=4
threshold=10
indexBoundary=3

for i->3 to 1, do
    array[i] = threshold/2^(pivot-i)
i=3, array[3] = 10/2^(4-3) = 10/2 = 5
i=2, array[2] = 10/2^(4-2) = 10/4 = 2.5
i=1, array[1] = 10/2^(4-1) = 10/8 = 1.25


for i->5 to 7, do
    array[i] = threshold/2^(i-pivot)
i=3, array[3] = 10/2^(5-4) = 10/2 = 5
i=2, array[2] = 10/2^(6-4) = 10/4 = 2.5
i=1, array[1] = 10/2^(7-4) = 10/8 = 1.25
```

Let me know if anything is not clear.